# increase Thread time out .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, wcf

I have a WCF method which does some calculation and insertion. This method is called in a thread. My method takes more than 45 minutes (which is fine for me) but after that it throws an error says "'Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding".
Only the insertion part is in transaction scope and in profiler I can see inserts happened only for less than a minute. I guess it is the thread which is timing out. How do I increase the time out ? Please help

Thanks
Ranjith

Comment: Your WCF method takes 45 minutes before it responds?

Comment: Does this thread do any SQL related work? Perhaps you could include the code where the exception is thrown?

Comment: You should probably split the application into two parts: A Windows service and a WCF service (or host the WCF service in the win service). The reason is that the application pool can recycle at any time and thus aborting the work before it has been completed. Doing it in a Windows Service is much more stable.

Comment: Agree with @jgauffin : WCF (and web applications in general) are not intended to handle >45 minutes requests ! You should do a service, or a background task (scheduled exe).

Comment: Actually, it is a call and forget logic I wanted to implement. Front end calls WCF and WCF calls a business layer where the threading starts. it is the calculation part which takes almost 40 minutes as it hits DB many times in a loop. It is timing out in 35 seconds after starting the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy to get around this issue that I used for a project.

We don't have your code so can so much guess, but if you're not in a hurry to have a response from your WCF server part you can actually sub-thread your computation part in the message handler and when you're ready - asynchronously - respond to your client in some ways. This way your message handler can respond straight away to your client request and no thread timeout will occur.

However, this implies that you might have to change the way your client/server work, such as regularly have your client request the server if its done with the computation.

To do an easy sub-threading in your client channel handler you could do this :

```
public MyObject payload = null;

// Called to initiate the computation on the channel
public bool StartComputation(MyParamClass param)
{
    // Reset payload to make sure 'IsComputationDone()' returns 'not ready' 
    payload = null;

    // Start thread where computation is done
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => {

        // Do computation with param
        // Payload is set when computation is done
        payload = doStuff(param);
    }

    return true;
}

// Called regularly to know if computation is ready
public bool IsComputationDone()
{
    return payload != null;
}

// Finally get payload
public MyObject GetResult()
{
    return IsComputationDone() ? payload : null;
}
```

That's the idea. After that you might want to add checks that you cannot run two computations at once with the same channel or at least manage a computation queue. Up to you, but this represents the basic approach

Comment: Although this MIGHT be good in theory. In practice this could cause all sorts of issues (especially if you run IIS). If it is in IIS, the ThreadPool call will be killed off by IIS. This maybe time to recognize the problem for what it is, which is a workflow/message queue.

Comment: It is true indeed that IIS is a trouble in that case but it isn't specified in the question that IIS is involved. However if IIS is required you could still work around delegating the computation part to an external classical app.

Comment: Thanks for the response.     Code which creates the thred is below:         "Dim OrdersThread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf CreateOrders)
                OrdersThread.Start()"
      CreateOrders is the method which has the calculation and insertion. I dont really bothered about the result as nothing to be shown in client side once process is done. I have configured a mail which will be sent once its done.